# How to make query_posts (tag OR tag) in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm primary frontend developer and I had an problem with some backend little thing.

I wanna to show posts with Tag1 OR Tag2.

In wordpress codex I found only this

```
<?php query_posts ($query_string . '&tag=apples+oranges'); ?>
```

but this is only AND funcionality.

I came with merging 2 query_posts arrays like

```
$tag1 = query_posts ($query_string . '&tag=tag1’);
$tag2 = query_posts ($query_string . '&tag=tag2’);                          
$tags = array_merge($tag1,$tag2);
//loop?
```

but how to get $tags array into wordpress loop?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

    //content

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>

    //no results content

<?php endif; ?>
```

For u it will be probably 1 minute, for me... u know

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't ever use `query_posts()` directly: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: Thank's for info man :) WP_Query works prefectly for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma `,` delimiter is equivalent to `OR` in a tag query apparently:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'bread,baking' ) );
while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    // Do stuff in the loop
endwhile;
```

More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

Comment: Thank's a lot man :) u saved me probably hours of my time within a minute :) I love u